# How to add automatically extension to Jupyter (ipython) notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, startup, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed extension `'calico-document-tools'` and I can load it from within Jupyter notebook using:

```
%%javascript
IPython.load_extensions('calico-document-tools');
```

How can I load it automatically for each opened notebook?

I tried adding `IPython.load_extensions('calico-document-tools');` or  `IPython.load_extensions('C:/Users/<username>/.ipython/nbextensions/calico-document-tools');` to `C:\Users\<username>\.ipython\profile_default\static\custom\custom.js` but it didn't work (extension should display a number of buttons on the toolbar).

I have only one profile, created with `ipython profile create`, Python 3.3, Windows 7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions && jupyter nbextension enable collapsible_headings/main`, for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To install the extensions I followed the instructions in [this notebook](http://jupyter.cs.brynmawr.edu/hub/dblank/public/Jupyter%20Help.ipynb) (not available anymore).

I adjusted them a little to be compatible with ipython4 (where the notebook server is called jupyter). This command installs the extension globally:

```
$ jupyter nbextension install https://github.com/Calysto/notebook-extensions/archive/master.zip
```

Then enable this extension:

```
$ jupyter nbextension enable calico-document-tools
```

When you now open or reload a notebook, it should load the extension

Updating the config to enable the extensions can also be done from inside the notebook:

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.config.update({
  "load_extensions": {"calico-spell-check":true,
                      "calico-document-tools":true,
                      "calico-cell-tools":true
                     }
})
```

Comment: At this moment, the calico tools are not supporting ipython4: https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/issues/219/ipython4-jupyter-support

Comment: `$ jupyter nbextension enable calico-document-tools` this is what made it work for me!

Comment: These commands add calico buttons on the toolbar, but these buttons do not perform any action at least for my setup: Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit) Jupiter 4.0.6. Probably this issue is not yet resolved: https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/issues/219/ipython4-jupyter-support