# How to hide Python 3 code in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

I'm using Python 3 in Jupyter Notebook for my data analysis, and I have to report to my boss about the results. Is there any way I can hide my code while still showing the output (like numbers and plots)? I've searched for it, but the only thing I could find was about IPython or code that doesn't work with mine.

Comment: There maybe an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159518/collapse-cell-in-jupyter-notebook) you can use.

Comment: You can save plots as a fig and just show that one.

Comment: What are you using if not iPython? Isn't that how Python is usually integrated with Jupyter?

Comment: the question was asked here before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer. Are those the approaches that do not work for you or is the question a duplicate? There is one promising answer from Noah from 2018 which might still work for you.