# Ensuring same page rendering for Jupyter with multiple Plotly plots, each time the page is opened?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am currently using Jupyter on a server:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
$ pip3 list | grep 'jupyter \|nbextensions\|plotly'
jupyter                           1.0.0
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions      0.5.1
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator 0.4.1
plotly                            5.2.2
```

My problem is this: I have an `.ipynb` notebook, with multiple Plotly plots inside, generated by multiple Python code cells.

Then, I have both:

- enabled "Initialization cells" on all Python code cells, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/39666438/6197439 , and saved the notebook
- Made a first `%%html` cell, with JavaScript to re-run all cells on page load, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/38856870/6197439 , and saved the notebook

Now, the results are like this:

- If the kernel corresponding to the `.ipynb` notebook, has been shut down, and then I open the `.ipynb` notebook in a new browser tab, then indeed all cells run, and after a some seconds wait, I get the graphs/plots rendered in the page, as I want it
- But if now I close that browser tab, and the kernel corresponding to this `.ipynb` notebook still runs, and I click the `.ipynb` notebook *again* so it opens in a new tab, this time the graphs/plots are NOT visible in the page (instead, the corresponding Python code cells are expanded, even if the original saved state is collapsed - where I use the Codefolding nbextension, see [collapse cell in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159518/))

  - Although, at this time, I can call Cell/Run All, and the Plotly plots are generated - but the corresponding code cells remain expanded

So, my question is: is there anything I can do, so that whenever the `.ipynb` page is opened for the first time, *all* the Plotly plots are generated - regardless if this is the first page load since the kernel started, or later page loads?