# Is there a more efficient way to organize/hide long functions in python?

Tags: function, hide

does anyone have an tips on how I can hide many functions in python? Is there a way I can have them saved in a file and just execute it, so I have it in memory but not taking up lines of cell code that is ugly? Or some easy method where I can just hide the cells?

I wonder why this hasn't been easily implemented yet, for example within Jupyter notebook which seems more interactive. Thanks.

Comment: are you asking specifically about collapsing code cells in jupyter notebook

Comment: Yes, that would be most efficient if that is possible!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [collapse cell in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159518/collapse-cell-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Yes exactly, just tried it out, thank you so much!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.