# (Toggle)collapse code block in jupyter-lab when output as HTML

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I did some search, and this can be done with [Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159518/collapse-cell-in-jupyter-notebook) by installing some nb-extensions. But I want a **jupyter-lab** version.

I want: when output ipynb to HTML, the code block and be toggle ON and OFF.

like [this](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/interactive/hiding.html) one, by clicking some button, the code cell can be expand(by default it is collapsed)

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52664156/6498757) answer, but this one made code togglable one by one, is there a batched method? So I don't need to add that function one block by one block.